# ¿Qué inconvenientes puede tener una api REST genérica?

Tags: c#, rest

Me imagine una API REST que apunte a una url similar a algo como esto:

```
/generico/stored_procedure/parma1=valor1/param2=valor2/../param_n=valor_n
```

Por lo que pude investigar entiendo que sería posible. La idea es que si el controlador recibe algo como esto:

```
/generico/ConsultaProductos/nombre=tornillo
```

Lo transforme automáticamente en una invocación a una base de datos similar a esto:

```
EXEC ConsultaProductos @nombre = 'tornillo'
```

Y el eventual recordset. si se trata de un método GET se transforme directamente en `json`. Obviamente, la idea es que tanto el SP como los parámetros sean variables en nombres y en cantidad de estos últimos. Habría seguramente alguna limitación para impedir que se pueda ejecutar cualquier SP de la base, pero la idea es mas o menos esta.

**Tengo en claro, en caso de poder hacer algo así, cual es el beneficio pero no tengo nada claro cuales serían los eventuales problemas o inconvenientes, en cuanto a seguridad, performance, etc.**

Comment: Me parece que el concepto se acerca a https://graphql.org/ La desventaja principal es el cache de las peticiones.

Answer (score 2):

Digamos que tienes el siguiente `endpoint`

```
[HttpGet("generic/{sp}")]
public ActionResult Get(string sp, Dictionary<string,string> parametros)
{
    //Aquí ejecutas el SP -> EXEC sp @nombre = 'tornillo'
    // Y haces un retorno de los datos
    //
}
```

Esto debería funcionar perfecto, pero hay un punto de seguridad que puede preocupar a algunos. Y es que cualquier cosa que ingreses como `sp`, se puede ejecutar, es decir puedes tener SP de uso privado que queden expuestos

Una solución sería crear una Lista de SP validos

```
private static string[] SPValidos = { "NompreSP1", "NompreSP1" };
[HttpGet("generic/{sp}")]
public ActionResult Get(string sp, Dictionary<string,string> parametros)
{
    if(!SPValidos.Contains(sp)) return NotFound(); //quizas hay otro código más apropiad
    //return algo
}
```

---

Luego, puedes querer que existan Roles asociados a cada SP que es lo habitual, para eso en lugar de una lista usamos un `Dictionary`

```
private static Dictionary<string, string[]> SPValidos = new()
{
    ["NompreSP1"] = new[] {"rol1","rol2"},
    ["NompreSP1"] = new[] { "rol3" },

};

[HttpGet("generic/{sp}")]
public ActionResult Get(string sp, Dictionary<string,string> parametros)
{
    if(!SPValidos.ContainsKey(sp)) return NotFound(); //quizas hay otro código más apropiado
    if (!SPValidos[sp].Any(User.IsInRole)) return Forbid();

   //return
}
```

---

Llegado a este punto uno puede pensar: *"Si tengo que escribir un diccionario de 200 items junto con sus roles, porque no hacer las cosas de manera standar"*

Entonces otra solución, no tan automática pero suficientemente versátil puede ser usar `MinimalApi`

Creamos un diccionario con la información de los `endpoint`

```
public static Dictionary<string, Endpoint> Endpoints = new()
{

    ["NombreSP1"] =  new Endpoint(){ 
        Nombre="Endpoint1",
        Summary ="Entrega algo",
        Descripción = "Una Descripción",
        Parametros = new List<Parametros>()
        {
            new Parametros()
            {
                Nombre ="Parametro1",
                Descripción ="Aqui va el primero parametro"
            },
                new Parametros()
            {
                Nombre ="Parametro2",
                Descripción ="Aqui va el segundo parametro"
            },
        }

    } 
};
```

**Todo este diccionario tu lo puedes tener en un archivo.json por fuera** y lo cargas al inicio. O tener múltiples archivo JSON uno por cada SP. La creación de este json se puede automatizar bastante, pero eso sería para otra pregunta

Y este diccionario puede ser mas o menos completo según tus necesidades, yo en el ejemplo he colocado una estructura suficiente para crear una documentación decente.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo completo:

```js
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

namespace WebApplication10;
   
public class Program
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Endpoint> Endpoints = new()
    {

        ["NombreSP1"] =  new Endpoint(){ 
            Nombre="Endpoint1",
            Summary ="Entrega algo",
            Descripción = "Una Descripción",
            Parametros = new List<Parametros>()
            {
                new Parametros()
                {
                    Nombre ="Parametro1",
                    Descripción ="Aqui va el primero parametro"
                },
                    new Parametros()
                {
                    Nombre ="Parametro2",
                    Descripción ="Aqui va el segundo parametro"
                },
            }

        } 
    };
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        

        foreach (var endpoint in Endpoints)
        {
            app.MapGet("/"+endpoint.Value.Nombre, async Task<IResult> (HttpContext httpContext) =>
            {
                //if (!endpoint.Value.Roles.Any(httpContext.User.IsInRole)) return Results.Forbid();
                if(endpoint.Value.Parametros.Count!= httpContext.Request.Query.Count) return Results.BadRequest();

                string paremetros = string.Join(", ", endpoint.Value.Parametros.Select(p => $"@{p.Nombre}={httpContext.Request.Query[p.Nombre]}"));
                string Exec = $"EXEC {endpoint.Key} {paremetros}";
                    
                return Results.Ok(Exec);
            })
            .WithName(endpoint.Value.Nombre)
            .WithOpenApi(operation => new(operation)
            {
                Summary =endpoint.Value.Summary,
                Description = endpoint.Value.Descripción,
                Parameters = endpoint.Value.Parametros.Select(p=> new OpenApiParameter()
                {
                    Name = p.Nombre,
                    Description =p.Descripción,
                    In = ParameterLocation.Query,
                    Schema = new OpenApiSchema()
                    {
                        Type = p.Tipo,
                        MaxItems=1,
                        UniqueItems = true,
                    }
                }).ToList()
            });
        }
          

        app.Run();
    }
}

public class Endpoint
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Descripción { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public string[] Roles { get; set; }
    public List<Parametros> Parametros { get; set; }
}

public class Parametros
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Descripción { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

El punto importante esta en recorrer el diccionario e ir generando los `endpoins`

```
foreach (var endpoint in Endpoints)
{
    app.MapGet("/" + endpoint.Value.Nombre, async Task<IResult> (HttpContext httpContext) =>
    {
        //return
    })
}
```

Según el ejemplo que te he puesto, ahora además contamos con documentación por
`SwaggerUI`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En cuanto a que cualquier cosa se puede ejecutar, eso lo puedes controlar de varias maneras, por ejemplo a nivel de base de datos, conectándote con un usuario que no tenga permisos para ejecutar lo que no se puede ejecutar, pero también usando un prefijo _prohibido_ en los SP's que son privados y con un simple if, o incluso manteniendo una tabla de usuarios o roles y sus _permisos_ para ejecutar tal o cual SP. El cielo es el límite.

Comment: @jachguate Concuerdo, si yo tuviera que entregar esto mañana lo haría de esa manera. Esta pregunta la conversamos ayer en el Chat y unos de los problemas que surgió fue la el que comento de que los SP quedan expuestos, además del tema de la documentación del swagger que se pierde. Yo me quedé pensado en eso y hoy se me ocurrió esta manera, que mediante un JSON se generarán los endpoints

Comment: La respuesta no es mala, pero a mi gusto, sigue siendo un tema que le va a faltar aristas... por ejemplo, tu respuesta solo toma en cuenta que los parametros sean siempre iguales, cosa que ayer quedo claro que no era asi.. entonces, donde estaria esa parte al construir los endpoints en base a un json??? no es tan trivial como parece...}

Comment: @gbianchi-enhuelga si expandes el código completo y miras esta linea `public static Dictionary<string, Endpoint> Endpoints = new()` ese diccionario representa el JSON con datos de prueba, el OP solo debe implementar una función que lea el JSON y lo parsee a `Dictionary<string, Endpoint>`.  Desde ese JSON se crean los endpoints con parámetros variables, un endpoint puede tener 2 parámetros y otro puede tener 40, eso lo configuras en el JSON.

Comment: @gbianchi-enhuelga Entonces, no es como dices. La respuesta contempla endpoint y parámetros variables configurados a partir de un diccionario que es fácil y directamente reemplazable por un JSON. Si mira el diccionario verás que hay 2 parámetros configurados y si miras la imagen te darás cuenta que el swagger muestra los mismos 2 parámetros

Comment: a mi no me queda claro.. pero obviamente si decis que esta, esta...